# How do you run redis for jaseci is there a specific command to run

Tags: jaseci

Is there a way that is jaseci specific to run redis in the terminal, because jaseci studio is complaining in the logs and the graphs is not working as expected because it requires redis.

I'm expecting redis to work on jsserv so that the graph can work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to run the standard `redis-server` in a separate terminal before starting `jsserv runserver`.

Assuming you're using an Ubuntu (or Debian) distro, to install redis-server use `sudo apt install redis-server`